# How to convert mp4 to mkv?

Tags: video, convert

I have a mp4 video which is 18.5GB, it doesn't has any appreciable quality, and it runs for 2hours and 40 minutes.

recently I came across a movie which was saved in mkv format and was of the same time and better quality and it was only of 0.78GB, I am using openshot, can any suggest me any other app or show me the way to convert mp4 into mkv?

Comment: If you done convert file from 18.5Gib to [even] -10Gib, please tell me know that too. thank you

Comment: @KasiyA i think the final file would be of 9 gb as the video is 50% enconded till this time and it is 4.6 gb at that instant, so i think it would do the job

Comment: Alright. thanks again. and what about @Toroidal's answer? did you try it?

Comment: Converting from mp4 to mkv won't change the filesize and/or quality. mp4 and mkv are containers. It sounds like you need to transcode the contents, increasing the compression and/or using a more space efficient codec.

Comment: @NGRhodes do you have any tips for me to do that, if yes, that would help me a lot

Comment: @KasiyA yes i did, but the task would long for 7 and a 1/2 hours so i left it midway

Comment: @NGRhodes but it happened with me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Handbrake.

> HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform,
>   multithreaded video transcoder, available for MacOS X, Linux and
>   Windows.<sup>[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

Or you can use Synaptic to install it.

To convert mMP4 to MKV, follow the steps below:

Click on the movie like icon, to choose the MP4 file to be converted.

[image]

Click on the file to select it

[image]

Make sure the output type is mkv, and then click on the green button to start the conversion.

[image]

Comment: handbrake-releases is known to be buggy. As an alternative, use the commands above, but change "/handbrake-releases" to "/handbrake-snapshots". Both will do MP4 and MKV, but the -snapshots version has more options

Comment: Why use any ppa at all? handbrake is in the universe-repository (from 14.04 at least) and works without a hitch. I've never had a problem with handbrake since I switched to it.

Comment: @mitch can you show me how to export a mp4 video to mkv using handbrake

Comment: @agharehanabbas see additions in my answer.

Comment: @Mitch i think there is a typo in your last terminal command, i thinks it is -gtk instead of -gtk1, but any ways i have done it

Comment: When you use Handbrake to convert the video I would recommend you set the bitrate to lossless, it will bloat the file size slightly but if you use the default settings and turn and MP4 compressed file and re-compress to MKV there will be serious quality loss, especially in the audio department.

Comment: @GhostMotleyX could you show me any way to compress mp$ files without or with a slight quality loss

Comment: Here is where the "lossless" setting is located
http://goo.gl/ybSYjI

Answer (score 12):

Download and install VLC player with one of the options provided here: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

Then run it by executing this command in Terminal:

```
vlc
```

Then once the program is open go "Media > Convert / Save...":

[image: "Media > Convert / Save..." option]

And in this interface which comes up click the "Add" button and locate the MP4 file which you wish to convert:

[image: Open Media window]

Then select the "Convert / Save" option at the bottom which now becomes enabled (not greyed out). Next select the profile "Video - H.264 + MP3 (MP4)" and then click on the little tool icon next to the pull-down menu and make sure that the option "MKV" is selected and not the default "MP4/MOV" like this:

[image: Profile edition options]

Then click the "Save" button at the bottom left. Then select the destination to where you want VLC player to export the file to and press "Start". Ignore any errors telling you about encoding problems. The progress bar which normally shows how far into the program you are will now show the progress of the conversion. When the progress bar has finished, your video will have been converted and ready to play.

Answer (score 12):

It is very simple, I tried and got succeed using the below ffmpeg command

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mkv`

Answer (score 4):

First, install avconv

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Next, translate via command line

```
avconv -i filme.mp4 -c copy filme.mkv
```

Converting this way produces a file with a similar size.
We need do add extra options to
define what transformations should be done to reduce space. (See `avconv -h`)

Answer (score 0):

`mkvmerge` (of [MKVToolNix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKVToolNix)) can be used for multiplexing into MKV:

```
mkvmerge --output FILE.mkv  FILE.mp4
```

Note that the output file (MKV) has to **precede the input file** (MP4) in the command.

Comment: I've noted that the question is essentially about encoding, but the body text is unclear and implausible.